# My grammar identifiers keywords as identifiers

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I'm trying to parse expressions from the Jakarta Expression Language. In summary, it is a simplified Java expressions, with addition of a few things:

- Support for creating maps like: `{"foo": "bar"}`
- Support for creating lists and sets like: `[1,2,3,4]` `{1,2,3,4}`
- Use some identifiers instead of symbols, like: `foo gt bar` (`foo > bar`), `foo mod bar`(`foo % bar)`, and so on.

I'm struggling in the last bit, where it always understands the "mod", "gt", "ge" as identifiers instead of using the expression that has the "%", ">", ">=".

I'm new to ANTLR. My grammar is based on the Java grammar in the https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/java/java and the JavaCC provided by: https://jakarta.ee/specifications/expression-language/4.0/jakarta-expression-language-spec-4.0.html#collected-syntax

```
grammar ExpressionLanguageGrammar;
prog: compositeExpression;

compositeExpression: (dynamicExpression | deferredExpression | literalExpression)*;
dynamicExpression: '${' expression RCURL;
deferredExpression: '#{' expression RCURL;
literalExpression: literal;

literal: BOOL_LITERAL | FLOATING_POINT_LITERAL | INTEGER_LITERAL | StringLiteral | NULL;
mapData | listData | setData;
methodArguments: LPAREN expressionList? RPAREN;
expressionList: (expression ((COMMA expression)*));
lambdaExpressionOrCall: LPAREN lambdaExpression RPAREN methodArguments*;
lambdaExpression: lambdaParameters ARROW expression;
lambdaParameters: IDENTIFIER | (LPAREN (IDENTIFIER ((COMMA IDENTIFIER)*))? RPAREN);

mapEntry: expression COLON expression;
mapEntries: mapEntry (COMMA mapEntry)*;

expression
    : primary
    |'[' expressionList? ']'
    | '{' expressionList? '}'
    | '{' mapEntries? '}'
    | expression bop='.' (IDENTIFIER | IDENTIFIER '(' expressionList? ')')
    | expression ('[' expression ']')+
    | prefix=('-' | '!' | NOT1 | EMPTY) expression
    | expression bop=('*' | '/' | '%' | MOD1 | DIV1) expression
    | expression bop=('+' | '-') expression
    | expression bop=('<=' | '>=' | '>' | '<' | LE1 | GE1 | LT1 | GT1) expression
    | expression bop=INSTANCEOF IDENTIFIER
    | expression bop=('==' | '!=' | EQ1 | NE1) expression
    | expression bop=('&&' | AND1) expression
    | expression bop=('||' | OR1) expression
    | <assoc=right> expression bop='?' expression bop=':' expression
    | <assoc=right> expression
           bop=('=' | '+=' | '-=' | '*=' | '/=')
           expression
    | lambdaExpression
    | lambdaExpressionOrCall
    ;

primary
    : '(' expression ')'
    | literal
    | IDENTIFIER
    ;

BOOL_LITERAL: TRUE | FALSE;
IDENTIFIER: LETTER (LETTER|DIGIT)*;
INTEGER_LITERAL: [0-9]+;
FLOATING_POINT_LITERAL: [0-9]+ '.' [0-9]* EXPONENT? | '.' [0-9]+ EXPONENT? | [0-9]+ EXPONENT?;
fragment EXPONENT: ('e'|'E') ('+'|'-')? [0-9]+;


StringLiteral:                 ('"' DoubleStringCharacter* '"'
             |                  '\'' SingleStringCharacter* '\'') ;

fragment DoubleStringCharacter
    : ~["\\\r\n]
    | '\\' EscapeSequence
    ;

fragment SingleStringCharacter
    : ~['\\\r\n]
    | '\\' EscapeSequence
    ;
fragment EscapeSequence
    : CharacterEscapeSequence
    | '0'
    | HexEscapeSequence
    | UnicodeEscapeSequence
    | ExtendedUnicodeEscapeSequence
    ;
fragment CharacterEscapeSequence
    : SingleEscapeCharacter
    | NonEscapeCharacter
    ;
fragment HexEscapeSequence
    : 'x' HexDigit HexDigit
    ;

fragment UnicodeEscapeSequence
    : 'u' HexDigit HexDigit HexDigit HexDigit
    | 'u' '{' HexDigit HexDigit+ '}'
    ;
fragment ExtendedUnicodeEscapeSequence
    : 'u' '{' HexDigit+ '}'
    ;
fragment SingleEscapeCharacter
    : ['"\\bfnrtv]
    ;

fragment NonEscapeCharacter
    : ~['"\\bfnrtv0-9xu\r\n]
    ;
fragment EscapeCharacter
    : SingleEscapeCharacter
    | [0-9]
    | [xu]
    ;
fragment HexDigit
    : [_0-9a-fA-F]
    ;
fragment DecimalIntegerLiteral
    : '0'
    | [1-9] [0-9_]*
    ;
fragment ExponentPart
    : [eE] [+-]? [0-9_]+
    ;
fragment IdentifierPart
    : IdentifierStart
    | [\p{Mn}]
    | [\p{Nd}]
    | [\p{Pc}]
    | '\u200C'
    | '\u200D'
    ;
fragment IdentifierStart
    : [\p{L}]
    | [$_]
    | '\\' UnicodeEscapeSequence
    ;

LCURL: '{';
RCURL: '}';
LETTER:  '\u0024' |
                 '\u0041'..'\u005a' |
                 '\u005f' |
                 '\u0061'..'\u007a' |
                 '\u00c0'..'\u00d6' |
                 '\u00d8'..'\u00f6' |
                 '\u00f8'..'\u00ff' |
                 '\u0100'..'\u1fff' |
                 '\u3040'..'\u318f' |
                 '\u3300'..'\u337f' |
                 '\u3400'..'\u3d2d' |
                 '\u4e00'..'\u9fff' |
                 '\uf900'..'\ufaff';
DIGIT: '\u0030'..'\u0039'|
               '\u0660'..'\u0669'|
               '\u06f0'..'\u06f9'|
               '\u0966'..'\u096f'|
               '\u09e6'..'\u09ef'|
               '\u0a66'..'\u0a6f'|
               '\u0ae6'..'\u0aef'|
               '\u0b66'..'\u0b6f'|
               '\u0be7'..'\u0bef'|
               '\u0c66'..'\u0c6f'|
               '\u0ce6'..'\u0cef'|
               '\u0d66'..'\u0d6f'|
               '\u0e50'..'\u0e59'|
               '\u0ed0'..'\u0ed9'|
               '\u1040'..'\u1049';
TRUE: 'true';
FALSE: 'false';
NULL: 'null';
DOT: '.';
LPAREN: '(';
RPAREN: ')';
LBRACK: '[';
RBRACK: ']';
COLON: ':';
COMMA: ',';
SEMICOLON: ';';
GT0: '>';
GT1: 'gt';
LT0: '<';
LT1: 'lt';
GE0: '>=';
GE1: 'ge';
LE0: '<=';
LE1: 'le';
EQ0: '==';
EQ1: 'eq';
NE0: '!=';
NE1: 'ne';
NOT0: '!';
NOT1: 'not';
AND0: '&&';
AND1: 'and';
OR0: '||';
OR1: 'or';
EMPTY: 'empty';
INSTANCEOF: 'instanceof';
MULT: '*';
PLUS: '+';
MINUS: '-';
QUESTIONMARK: '?';
DIV0: '/';
DIV1: 'div';
MOD0: '%';
MOD1: 'mod';
CONCAT: '+=';
ASSIGN: '=';
ARROW: '->';
DOLLAR: '$';
HASH: '#';

WS: [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the Lexer rules for them to be prior to the Lexer rule for `Identifier`.

If ANTLR has more than one Lexer rule that matches input of the same length it chooses the first rule in the grammar that matches.

For example “mod” is matched by `Identifier` and `MOD1`, but `Identifier` is 1st, so it chooses `Identifier`.  Move the `MOD1` rule to be before `Identifier` and it’ll match `MOD1`

———-

BTW, unless you care about having different token values for “%” and “mod”, you can just define a single rule:

```
MOD: ‘%’ | ‘mod’;
```

You’d can still get the token text if you need it but it will you can just specify `MOD` in your parser rules instead of `(MOD0 | MOD1)`

Comment: Thank you SO much, you don't know how much time I've spent on this.